# Using NINI with IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, isolatedstorage, nini

I'm trying to save some configuration info and I wish to use NINI library and files within IsolatedStorage. I don't know why but when I try to save the configuration I got the following  exception on Nini Save method: Source cannot be saved in this state

Here's the code:

```
        isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly | IsolatedStorageScope.Domain, null, null);
        var isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("file.ini", FileMode.Create, isf);
        //Stream s = new StreamWriter(isfs);

        IConfigSource mainSource = new IniConfigSource(isfs);

        var config1 = mainSource.Configs["General"];

        if (config1 == null)
        {
            mainSource.AddConfig("General");
            config1 = mainSource.Configs["General"];
        }
        config1.Set("CW", CommentWidth);
        mainSource.Save();

        isfs.Close();
```

The exception happens in mainSource.Save(); . Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the constructor documentation for [`IniConfigSource(Stream)`](http://nini.sourceforge.net/Reference/html/index.html):

> This is a non-savable source unless you call one of the overloaded [Save](http://nini.sourceforge.net/Reference/html/Nini.Config.IniConfigSource.Save_overload_1.html) methods.

So, you probably want [`Save(Stream)`](http://nini.sourceforge.net/Reference/html/index.html). You might want to Seek the stream back to the origin before passing it to `Save`.

---

Contrary to your comments, I tried this out, and discovered that the `isfs` stream had been closed (presumably by the constructor method - it's not documented what it will do to the stream) - so I got a *different* error message. This led me to re-initializing `isfs` and, as I had said, passing it to the `Save` method:

```
isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("file.ini", FileMode.Create, isf);
((IniConfigSource)mainSource).Save(isfs);
```

and it works fine.

Comment: Is not working either. This code works just fine using a regular FileStream.

Comment: @DavidFornas - Okay, but you haven't told us what exception you're getting - and is it the same exception with my suggested modification? "not working" isn't a helpful diagnostic.

Comment: I did: Source cannot be saved in this state